# Problem using a .bst file in TeXShop--TeXShop cannot find file

Tags: bibtex, installing

I am trying to use `spbasic.bst` to work on a manuscript for a journal.  I copied the file into

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/tex/bibtex/bst
```

and ran texhash. However, TeXShop doesn't find the file.  When I run bibtex I get the error:

```
I couldn't open style file spbasic.bst
---line 12 of file MyDocument.aux
 : \bibstyle{spbasic
 :                  }
```

If the `.bst` file is in the same folder as the .tex document it works fine.  I would like to use this `.bst` file for other projects as well and I don't want to have to copy and paste it every time.   Have I put the `.bst` file in the wrong location?  Or is there something I am missing?  I am running TeXShop 2.41 on OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good idea to put non TeX Live files in the main distribution tree: an update will make the file disappear or unavailable anyway. It's probably a permission problem: did you run `texhash` prefixed by `sudo`?

Nevertheless, the best strategy is to put your `.bst` under

```
~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst
```

creating the necessary folders. If you need to make the file available to all users of your machine, then the place is

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bst
```

If you're not afraid of the Terminal, the sequence of commands is

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bst
sudo cp spbasic.bst /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bst
sudo mktexlsr
```

The first method (that is, the folder below your Home) doesn't require `mktexlsr`.

You should also upgrade to MacTeX 2011.

Comment: @kirk65537: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.